# Using a Pi as storage from a dashcam

Tags: wifi, storage

I have a dashcam that writes to a SDXC card. I would like to replace this card with a Pi and store my video on it then when I get home have the Pi automatically connect to my WiFi and transfer the video to a NextCloud server I have on my network.

I would appreciate all advise on where o start.

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as an adapter that could be put in to replace the SD card and connect the Pi.

Comment: unless the dashcam is built on opensource and there is ample documentation about the interfaces the dashcam offers, this would be near impossible. you might be better off, building your own 'dashcam' using the pi + a good pi-camera. if i were to do this, i'd create a 'dashcam' first using the `libcamera` library. then i'd script polling to look specific wifi connection and kick off a `SFTP` file transfer when the connection is detected.